# Scala + Lift or Ruby on Rails, for a beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scala, comparison, lift

thanks for opening my question :)

I am a university student in Computer Engineering, and I've always done class projects in Java (apart from C, and Assembly, but for very specific things). Apart from that, I have worked for quite a lot of time on a web app done in ActionScript 3, contained in .jsp files and deployed onto a Google App Engine site.

Having that said, I now pretend to do a prototype of another web app, which will have registered users with blogs and a messaging system between them.

My question is, having time as a restraint (I have month and a half), and needing just to build a working prototype, could anyone tell me, in his/her opinion, what would be the best framework for me to start learning and use? (Take into account my Java & ActionScript background) I believe RoR is the most common in these cases, as its easy and quick, but I have no Ruby knowledge at all, and maybe it would be quicker for me to learn Scala (which coming fromJava shouldn't be that different) and Lift, and do it with them instead.

Many thanks in advance!

Pepillo

Comment: First off- since this is an opinion question it probably doesn't belong on SO. But I will give you my opinion: coming from Java, Scala is awesome and personally it did not take too long to learn. Trying to learn Lift at the same time was a bit difficult for me, but it has been very rewarding. Given that you have no Ruby knowledge, I would recommend going with Scala+Lift for whatever you're doing

Comment: Thanks Dylan! By the way, is there any resource (book, videocourse, etc) that you would higly recommend me for the migration? For Lift, I guess that simplyLift guide is the way to go, but I'm not sure what would be the best for learning Scala beforehand!

Comment: "Off Topic". However, *I personally prefer* statically-typed languages *that have type inference* (Please don't confuse Scala with Java!!!). Take that as you will, and YMMV :) There are other web-frameworks than LiftWeb or Rails: you may find different frameworks more suitable depending upon application/requirements/preferences/integration.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but the Play! framework is supposedly a bit easier to get going with than Lift. http://scala.playframework.org/ You won't regret learning Scala, but with only 6 weeks you could try Play's Java version.

Comment: @pepillo I used O'Reilly's online book, "Programming Scala", found here: http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/

Comment: I think I'm going with Play! Not only is the easiest for me, as I am a Java guy, but it's also the quickest when in conjuntion with Japid [link](http://www.jtict.com/blog/rails-wicket-grails-play-lift-jsp/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'm going with Play! Not only is the easiest for me, as I am a Java guy, but it's also the quickest when in conjuntion with Japid, according to a benchmark I saw.

Answer (score 2):

Last year I found myself in a very similar situation for creating a web based relationship browser for a computing science class. I would highly recommend RoR. Granted you will need to spend some time getting up to speed with Ruby, but it is well worth the small amount of time to learn. There is excellent documentation available and a ton of good tutorials.

Rails can generate much of the core code and database schema with the generator functions in seconds (see scaffolding generators). Considering your time constraint, I think this alone makes rails a good choice.

In terms of learning Ruby, you should not have much trouble with this if you are comfortable with any dynamically typed scripting languages.

Anyway, that has been my experience with rails. Good luck on your project!

Comment: Thanks! But as I wrote in a comment above, I'm finally probably going to go with Play! which is Java written, similar to RoR in its philosophy, but quite faster and scalable, which can be nice for future works on the same project.

Answer (score 1):

I used Java for about 7 years now, mostly for web applications, and recently started using RoR. I must say it was really easy to pick up and get started. After only 2 months of working on my own project I started using it for a customer projects and it was far more easier to deliver production code then I had anticipated. So yes I can recommend Ruby and it was not hard at all to pick up.

However, RoR does require a nix platform like apple os or linux. I stated out with windows but there are simply too many drawbacks and bugs.

If you decide to go with ruby I can higly recommend [Agile Web Development with Rails (Pragmatic Programmers)](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails.) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks! But as I wrote in a comment above, I'm finally probably going to go with Play! which is Java written, similar to RoR in its philosophy, but quite faster and scalable, which can be nice for future works on the same project.